# Having trouble fixing my title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, pagination, title

I'm using this code in order to display what page the user is.

```
<title><?php 
    global $page, $paged; 
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); 
    bloginfo( 'name' ); 
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' ); 
    if ( $site_description && ( is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description"; 
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) 
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s' ), x( $paged, $page ) ); 
?></title>
```

When clicking on the navigation it seem to be working properly and it also displays the correct title. But when I click on the pagination, the website shows only a blank page.

I'm using [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) plugin to display the pagination.

When I hovered on the tab an error appeared:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the second last line in your code block.

You have "x( $paged, $page ) );"

I think you should remove the "x", character.

EDIT: in fact, the correct (and accepted) solution is to replace "x" with "max" (see comment below)

Comment: I downloaded the plugin and checked for the existence of a function called x().  It doesn't exist so must be incorrect.

Judging from the following link, you should replace the "x" with "max" i.e. echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s'), max( $paged, $page ) );
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/site-title-missing